# ISO 8583 Rev.93 - Connecting to channel

Tags: c#, iso8583, core-banking

I'm fairly new to the whole ISO8583 concept and have been assigned to connect to a Bank's channel.

I have used John Oxley's Excellent [OpenIso8583.Net](http://code.google.com/p/openiso8583net/) to make a Iso8583-standard message and send it via tcp.

They provided me some basic information which i cannot manage to understand clearly.
Unfortunately, I do not have any resources available for more information and was hoping to get some guides from the community.

The bank has given me a test Card Number (PAN)(16 digits), a PIN Code(4 digits), an Outlet number, and a MAC Key.

Here's what I have so far:

- in msg[Iso8583Rev93.Bit._002_PAN] goes the PAN.
- in msg[Iso8583Rev93.Bit._052_PIN_DATA]: They have provided me an algorithm to generate a 16 byte PIN block based on PAN and PIN Code. I have managed to generate a correct PIN block based on that algorithm.

The things I don't have any idea about:

- They stated that PIN BLOCK is encrypted using DES algorithm. Where should I put the encrypted PIN block? it's more that 16 bytes and cannot be in msg[Iso8583Rev93.Bit._052_PIN_DATA] right?
- How should I make use of the MAC key they have provided for me? They stated that MAC is generated using DES-CBC algorithm. the MAC key they have provided is 16 bytes long(16 digits). What should I put in msg[Iso8583Rev93.Bit._128_MAC] field? Should I encrypt the whole message with this MAC key? I seem to be lost in understanding what the MAC key is used for.
- What's the use of the outlet number?Is it something like a port number (a software slot if you call it) to allow users to connect to channel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kindly find answers to your queries:

The things I don't have any idea about:

1. **They stated that PIN BLOCK is encrypted using DES algorithm. Where should I put the encrypted PIN block? it's more that 16 bytes and cannot be in msg[Iso8583Rev93.Bit._052_PIN_DATA] right?**

      Encrypted PIN Block should go to the bit 052, you should not pass a clear PIN Block, if the result of your encrypted PIN Data is more than 16 digits, then there is something wrong in your algorithm; DES & 3DES should have a cyclic behavior and the outcome should be restricted to 16 digits.
2. **How should I make use of the MAC key they have provided for me? They stated that MAC is generated using DES-CBC algorithm. the MAC key they have provided is 16 bytes long(16 digits). What should I put in msg[Iso8583Rev93.Bit._128_MAC] field? Should I encrypt the whole message with this MAC key? I seem to be lost in understanding what the MAC key is used for.**

      you should have in the specification provided by the bank a list of selected fields to be MACed, usually it is:

   - PAN (DE2)
   - Amount (DE4)
   - Track Data (DE35 or DE45)
   - PIN Data (DE52)
   - from & to accounts (DE102 & DE 103)
3. **What's the use of the outlet number?Is it something like a port number (a software slot if you call it) to allow users to connect to channel?**

    Usually outlet number is some data related to the acquiring bank, it would be related to the field 42

*I would emphasize on one point, that ISO8583 is not a strict framework, where both parties who decided to use as means of integration should decide on the specifics of data passed in each field*